# Транспонировать двумерную матрицу

Tags: php, массивы, циклы

Здравствуйте. Помогите, пожалуйста, решить вопрос. Есть матрица n*m представленная в скрипте в виде 2х-мерного массива `$a`. Нужно транспонировать эту матрицу и сохранить ее в переменную `$b`.

Я решил этот вопрос таким образом:

```
<?php
$a = array (
    array (1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 9),
    array (4, 7, 3, 3, 1, 5)
);

echo "\$arr = array (<br />
    array (1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 9),<br />
    array (4, 7, 3, 3, 1, 5);<br />
)";

array_unshift ($a, null);
$a = call_user_func_array("array_map", $a);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($a);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Это почти то, что нужно, если не учитывать, что я не сохранил результат в переменную `$b`, а просто вывел результат. Но это не все - теперь мне нужно сделать то же самое, только с помощью циклов foreach, а я в упор не понимаю, как это реализовать. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться. Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Правильно ли я понимаю, что вы хотите из

```
$a = array( array(1,2,3,6,8,9), array(4,7,3,3,1,5) );
```

получить:

```
$b = array( array(1,4), array(2,7), array(3,3), array(6,3), array(8,1), array(9,5) );
```

?

Если да, то можно обойтись *while*:

```
$b = array();
list($ar1, $ar2) = $a;

while($ar1) {
  $b[] = array(array_shift($ar1), array_shift($ar2));
}
```

Вариант с *foreach* (без list(), но можно и с ним):

```
$c = array();

foreach($a[0] as $k => $v ) {
  $c[] = array($v, $a[1][$k]);
}
```

Comment: Да, вы правильно поняли, так мне и нужно сделать. Большое спасибо за ответ. Но если не сложно, могли бы вы еще показать, как сделать такое же только через foreach?

Comment: Добавил вариант в ответ.